# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable error

Tags: java, android, import

Hi i have a problem with importing support.v7.appcompat. I imported android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity to my libs folder, but when i start running i get this log:

```
11-01 17:35:42.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1873): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 17:35:42.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1873): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
11-01 17:35:42.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:109)
11-01 17:35:42.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
11-01 17:35:42.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
11-01 17:35:42.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at morisson.Notowaniagieldowe.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
11-01 17:35:42.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-01 17:35:42.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-01 17:35:42.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
11-01 17:35:42.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-01 17:35:42.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-01 17:35:42.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-01 17:35:42.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-01 17:35:42.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-01 17:35:42.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-01 17:35:42.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-01 17:35:42.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-01 17:35:42.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-01 17:35:42.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-01 17:35:42.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and here is my MainActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);



        // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 
            MainActivity.this));

        // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }

}
```

I have seen some solution for this problem in other posts but it does not work for my case. Any suggestions?

Comment: Show your build.gradle file inside app module .

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android Studio then put this line inside your build.gradle file

```
    dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"
}
```

Comment: Put above line and sync build.gradle file .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse

- Delete the jar from the libs folder.
- Import the sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\ project in your eclipse workspace.
- Ensure that the android-support-v4.jar is the same in your project.
- Add the appcompat as a library to your project.

Ensure that your in yout Manifest.xml your activity has the correct theme

```
<activity
    android:name="***.*****.******"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
     >
```

And if your are using Android Studio

Put this line inside your build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
  compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"
}
```

Comment: I have done what Ferdousur Rhman wrote. Now i have other problem:  11-01 18:57:24.517: E/AndroidRuntime(867): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{morisson.Notowaniagieldowe/morisson.Notowaniagieldowe.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
11-01 18:57:24.517: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
11-01 18:57:24.517: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)